# How to navigate to C-hard drive with CMD?

Tags: cmd

So i want to go to my `C:` hard drive using `cmd.exe`.
But when it opens up it is immediately pointed to `C:\Users\username\`
I have tried to use `cd C:` but to no avail.

I have an extremely limited knowledge of cmd so my apologies if my question seems straightforward to you guys.

Comment: @BURNS: Please do not add "solved" to your question title. If one of the answers helped you to solve the problem, [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/220538) by clicking the check mark in the left margin. If none of the answers were useful and you figured out a solution of your own, post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try with this like:

```
cd\
```

or

```
cd..   //To go to parent directory
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should try the following command:

```
cd c\
```

Comment: no i get redirected to users\username

Answer (score 0):

Try `cd..` to navigate to the parent directory.